# Objective-C return types: "-(id) init" vs "-(ClassName *) init"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was following this beginner tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1, and I had a question regarding this class and its implementation here:

```
 RWTScaryBugData.h

 @interface RWTScaryBugData : NSObject

 @property (strong) NSString *title;
 @property (assign) float rating;

 - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title rating:(float)rating;
 @end
```

---

```
RWTScaryBugData.m

@implementation RWTScaryBugData

@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize rating = _rating;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title rating:(float)rating {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.title = title;
        self.rating = rating;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I'm looking at this initializer:

```
 - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title rating:(float)rating {
 }
```

Instead of writing it like that, I could also write it like this:

```
  - (RWTScaryBugData *)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title rating:(float)rating {
    }
```

Can anyone tell me the difference? Or, if it doesn't really matter?

Comment: `- (instancetype)` Is also possible, and if I remember correct recommend by Apple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Returning `id` instead of the class was a convention in Objective-C used to allow subclasses to override that initializer and return their type. For example, for a long time the `array` class method on `NSArray` returned `id` so that `NSMutableArray` could override that method and return a mutable array, so both of these were possible:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // Wouldn't be possible if the method returned (NSArray *)
```

The problem with this was that you could also say:

```
NSString *string = [NSArray array]; // bad
```

and that would typecheck. Apple introduced `instancetype` as a new return type, which returns the class in which `instancetype` declaration is being used. Today, the `array` method returns `instancetype` so that the first 2 examples above typecheck, but the bad example won't typecheck.

More more details, see the [NSHipster article on the subject](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/).

Comment: `instancetype` means the method returns the type of the _reciever of the message_, not the type in which the method declaration was made (that would the same as `+ (Thingy *)thingy`). It is also unnecesary for `init...` methods; [the compiler knows](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types).

Answer (score 5):

In these scenarios the recommended return type is `instancetype`.
This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW2).

Comment: `instancetype` [is inferred](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types) for `init...` methods; it is not necessary to use it explicitly.

Comment: Inferring related result types is compiler-specific behavior and should not be assumed. The recommended return type, per Apple's documentation, is still `instancetype`.

Comment: Using `instancetype` in the first place is compiler-specific behavior. Only Clang recognizes it.

Comment: Further, the doc you linked says "Even though the compiler automatically converts methods that begin with “alloc,” “init,” or “new” and have a return type of `id` to return `instancetype`, it doesn’t convert other methods."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any perk besides being able to re-use (by that I mean copy/paste) an initialization method without having to modify the return type.

It is actually kind of a bad practice to use id actually, since there is no compile-time type-checking with the id return type. Actually, the convention is to use instancetype instead of id (or the class name), because it has the perks of both.